# Print color compatibility (CMYK) in document (especially pgfplots)

Tags: pgfplots, color, cmyk

Because I intend to print my work, I'd like to have all figures and graphics in CMYK colour space. I know that I can define colours in CMYK with the `xcolor` package, e.g.:

```
\definecolor{col1}{cmyk}{0.86, 0.61, 0, 0}
```

Firstly, `xcolor` doesn't throw a error (or a warning) if a colour is out of gamut (I checked some colours with Illustrator) - which means for my understanding, that they might look different when printed. But okay, I can deal with this (even though it's cumbersome). Secondly, when I use colourmaps from e.g. colorbrewer, how can I know if they only consist of CMYK colours?

Everything imported to the tex-file isn't a real problem because I can (and most likely will have to because it's easier to handle) adapt/convert before I import it.

Is there any way to solve these two issues (the second one is the bigger issue for me actually)?

Edit: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        stack plots=y,stack dir=minus,
        colormap/PuOr-5,
        cycle list/PuOr-5]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your TeX-related question? Yes, you can use CMYK colors as you already know.

Comment: The TeX-related question is regarding the colormaps. Where do I get colourmaps in CMYK colour space from? I used e.g. the standard bluered colormap from pgfplots but that was obviously not in CMYK (I imported the graphic in Illustrator and changed the colorspace and it looked totally different, hence, it would have also looked totally different after printing). I use `colorbrewer` now but I can't find the information if these colours are in CMYK

Comment: I have no experience with ColorBrewer, but they seem to have  a “print friendly” option. The accompanying info mentions  “CMYK specs”.

Comment: I don't have to stick to ColorBrewer. I just want to avoid to make colormaps or cyclic lists for surface plots on my own.

Comment: How can we know if you did setup your document correctly for cmyk?  If you had provided a small example, someone could check the code and the resulting pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a MWE

Comment: All colors in the `colorbrewer` library are defined in RGB color space only, as can be seen in the [tikzlibrarycolorbrewer.code.tex](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/blob/master/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarycolorbrewer.code.tex) file. Although the colors have corresponding CYMK definitions too, as can be seen on https://colorbrewer2.org, I think we didn't define both of them because of the limitation of the `\pgfutil@definecolor` command, which only supports one color space.

Comment: I see, nevertheless it's one thing that they have corresponding CMYK definitions and another on if they are in gamut or not. I haven't had this issue before because I only needed a few (self defined) colours. But I have a lot of surface plots and multi shaded graphics in my document now. I'm a little bit astonished that everything seems to work in RGB in TeX even though it is very much used to produce also documents to be printed (at least at that stage, all those things come together). Is there any other alternative which defines colormaps in CMYK (in gamut)?